# FOSCommentBundle how to implement

Tags: php, symfony, foscommentbundle

Is there some examples to implement this? Don't show nothing on my page.

```
{% include 'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig' with {'id': 'foo'} %}
```

I don't understand how to place this code and what will show on my page.

And when i place this on my `config.yml`

```
    assetic:
         bundles: [ "FOSCommentBundle" ]
```

Creates an error:

Unrecognized option "assetic" under "fos_comment".

My configuration:

fos_comment:
    db_driver: orm
    class:
        model:
            comment: BackEndBundle\Entity\Comment
            thread: BackEndBundle\Entity\Thread

assetic:
    bundles: [ "FOSCommentBundle" ]

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Specify one problem at time it's the best way to get a fast help and for us to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Did you follow this https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md  guide?

Comment: I never used FOSCommentBundle but seems from the error that the `assetic` otpion doesn't exist under the `fos_comment` sector. Have you double checked all the integration process to be sure to followed correctly the docs?

Comment: @AliNiaz yes i followed all the documentation from github but didn't work : (

Comment: Are you using also FOSUserBundle?

Comment: @gp_sflover Im new  using symfony. I need to implement comments on my site to interact users. But i don't know how to do it manualy so i tried to use this bundle because to create users and admin them i used FOSUsersBundle.

Comment: So you've followed the [Step: Integration with FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/6-integration_with_fosuserbundle.md)?

Comment: Exist other bundle to create comments on symfony and works with Symfony 3 ? I'm really lost. There isn't much information on Friendsofsymfony github.

Comment: @gp_sflover yes i did :S

Comment: check your AsseticBundle configurations follow this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html

Comment: Unfortunately I never used this bundle and I haven't much time now but after a fast looking to the docs it doesn't seem much complicated. Symfony have a moderate learning curve that mostly depends by your general programming knowledge. Maybe you will need a full tutorial example but this is off-topic here.

Comment: @AliNiaz Thanks that solves one problem. Still showing nothing about comments but the error has gone.
I didn't notice that Symfony3 doesn't give AsseticBundle by default.

Comment: can you show us the code area where you made changes during configuration?

Comment: @AliNiaz Which area ? I just followed the steps on tutorial. No i dont get any error but the text dont apear.
I'don't know if i need to place something else on my view or just only this
{% include 'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig' with {'id': 'foo'} %} .

Comment: check browser console for any js related errors.

Comment: @AliNiaz i checked but there is no error of js.

Comment: please run command assets:install, than check for console js errors in browser as     I have mentioned earlier.

Comment: @AliNiaz like this ? https://gyazo.com/dcf53ed72f8fd45f843eaabaf4205cc3

Comment: yes like this and also run doctrine:schema:update after doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Comment: @AliNiaz  Cmd said nothing to update. Im not sure if this should create table comment and thread on my database but i dnt got it.

Comment: did you run doctrine:cache:clear-metadata first?

Comment: @AliNiaz yes i did : (

Comment: I have managed to make this bundle work for me, I will post all the parts of code in the answer below please follow the steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have configure the bundle and have created the require classes like this

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment as BaseComment;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")
 */
class Comment extends BaseComment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Thread of this comment
     *
     * @var Thread
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Thread")
     */
    protected $thread;
}
```

And Thread.php like this

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread as BaseThread;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")
 */
class Thread extends BaseThread
{
    /**
     * @var string $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

In your config.yml, you will now have something like this

```
fos_comment:
    db_driver: orm
    class:
        model:
            comment: AppBundle\Entity\Comment
            thread: AppBundle\Entity\Thread
```

run the following commands

```
doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
doctrine:schema:update --force
```

After this you will have tables in the database for the entities
Now include this at top of the template

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

where you've included this

```
{% include 'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig' with {'id': 'foo'} %}
```

Clear both dev and prod cache after this step.
PS: I have selected the doctrine ORM method

Comment: Thanks i change some errors on my ORM comments and follow your steps and now its working. Thanks for your help i really apreciated !

Comment: I am glad it helped.